# Javascript passing argument: Strange Syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I started to study javascript, and coming from .net background I found the following code:

File express.js:

```
var express = require('express');
module.exports = function() {
    var app = express();
    require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')(app);
    return app;
};
```

File index.server.routes.js:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var index = require('../controllers/index.server.controller');
    app.get('/', index.render);
};
```

As the book was explaining the index.server.routes.js have this function(app), and app is the express object used to configuration(it is configuring the '/' path). That is ok.

What I do not understand is the following syntax:

```
require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')(app);
```

What I understand is that he is passing the app argument to the index.server.routes.js module and this module is setting the get.

But can anyone me explain how this syntax works? Coming from .net background, it seems to me a casting(very strange and confusing).

Comment: What is this `require` function? Is this different than native Javascript? If so, please the question as such.

Comment: require is CommonJS function used to load javascript modules... CommonJS is a standard.

Comment: `require()` is a function that returns a function. The function it returns is specific to the arguments passed in. This example is simply calling the returned function immediately and with the app parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is the syntax for calling functions. `index.server.routes.js` exports a function, therefore you can call it. Think that it is the same as:

```
var routes = require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')
routes(app) // routes is a function
```

It is common in Express to pass your `app` instance around as a form of explicit dependency injection.

Comment: Yes It is the same. Could you provide more background on the require('...')(app) syntax? Is it very used, is it a good practice = ]...
Ps* I can only accept within 7 minutes.

Comment: `require` is just Node modules, nothing specific to Express. See here http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

It is rather simple. When you call `require` in Node.js, Node will load the module (the file), and return to you whatever that module exported via the `module.exports` property. In this case, it exported a function.

As such, `require` gives you a function and thus you can immediately call it by putting the parentheses right after the `require` statement.

The code is equivalent of doing this:

```
var routesFn = require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')
routesFn(app)
```